# Outbound link autometic converted into linkdirect , and not opening

Tags: plugins, posts, permalinks

Outbound links are **automatically converted into linkdirect link**, and not opening. But internal links are fine. I use wp Nofollow plugin, currently, I deleted the plugin but **no luck**.

Please check **my article**:- https://www.holidaystory.in/visit-love-india-travel-rough-guides/

The error is :-[image]{"error":"Sorry, User is not available"}